# What are ways to describe when someone gives a curious look or if their interest is piqued

Tags: american-english, writing, gestures

I usually use something along the lines of blatantly saying "He gave a curious look/shot a curious glance."

However, does anyone know ways to describe someone gesturing with their face a curious look rather than outright saying that? Since what I've done is pretty amateur. I've used "raised a brow" but I'd rather not go on doing it.

Comment: "I'd rather continue not to." does not correspond to the present context. I think that what you mean is "I'd rather not go on doing it.".

Comment: Why so many curious glances? Did something happen?

Comment: What's wrong with _glanced curiously_?

Comment: I agree that you need to find another way to say that since in both of those examples it's unclear whether the speaker is curious or the subject "he" is curious, like, "He gave a curious look," could mean he had a look or looked on in a manner that made him appear to be curious but could also mean that he gave a look that made the speaker curious about it. Essentially, it's the difference between, "He looked curiously," and, "He looked curious," respectively.

Comment: Ah, yeah I literally was just telling someone on something is written/said, and here I go and do it myself. 

"Looked Curiously" would of course implied, he looked at something curiously, where as a curious look, is simply someone gesturing a look of curiosity.

Comment: Don't you think someone giving a curious look would be not at all comparable to but rather the result of their interest being piqued?

Answer (score 1):

You **prick up your ears** if you pay sudden attention, usually to something you've heard. The metaphor relates to an animal hearing a sudden noise and moving its ears to listen better.

You'll find it in most dictionaries, e.g. [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/prick-up-your-ears) says "*prick (up) your ears* phrase: to start listening to something very carefully because it sounds interesting" Example: *I pricked up my ears when I heard my name mentioned.*

[The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/prick+up+your+ears) has "To pay sudden close attention to something one overhears." One example is: *I can't help but prick up my ears if I hear someone say my name—even if they aren't talking about me.*

It is sometimes used in a metaphorical sense if something isn't actually heard, but usually it implies hearing.

Visually something can **catch someone's eye**. This has two meanings, when you attract someone's attention, but more relevantly, when you see something interesting/unusual and it attracts your attention.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/catch-eye) gives both definitions: "to get someone's attention; to get someone's attention, especially by looking at them; to be attractive or different enough to be noticed by someone". Example: *It was the unusual colour of his jacket that caught my eye.*

Answer (score 0):

Try using **quizzical**

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/quizzical)
> *quizzical*
> expressing slight uncertainty or amusement

M-W has a related definition that also echoes your purpose and even offers an eyebrow example:

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quizzical)
> *quizzical*
> expressive of puzzlement, curiosity, or disbelief
> raised a quizzical eyebrow